# How to convert all mp3 audio in a folder to 8d or 9d audio in ubuntu terminal

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, mp3, sox

In ubuntu terminal, is there any command to make all mp3 in a folder to 8d or 9d audio. Something like ffmpeg or other?

According to mashable,

> 8D audio is essentially an effect applied to a stereo track where songs have been edited with spacial reverb and mixing to make it seem like the audio moving in a circle around your head. This experience can only be achieved by wearing headphones, which the gimmick relies upon to create the illusion of a 360 degree space.

[Mashable link](https://in.mashable.com/culture/2354/8d-audio-is-an-innovative-sonic-experience-that-can-transport-you-to-another-dimension)

Comment: Explain what 8d and 9d audio is. Will not be very commonly know, I guess. I see from your tags you also explored `sox ` already.

Comment: I edited my question. Added some explanations.

Comment: https://github.com/dakshj48/8D-Audio-Converter "In ubuntu terminal, is there any command to make all mp3 in a folder to 8d or 9d audio. Something like ffmpeg or other?" No you need a python script for that.

Comment: @Rinzwind I get following error after uploading mp3 in localhost:5000 `KeyError
KeyError: 'TIT2'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/home/justine/web/8D-Audio-Converter/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2328, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/justine/web/8D-Audio-Converter/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2314, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/home/justine/web/8D-Audio-Converter/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1760, in handle_exception
`

Comment: Error is probably happening due to some problems in ID3 tags, you may remove tag processing, for that comment [this line](https://github.com/dakshj48/8D-Audio-Converter/blob/330417840156047651f2db355055f3858681c410/audioCon.py#L16) and replace `bitrate=str(fileinfo.info.bitrate), tags=tags(fileinfo)` with `bitrate='320000'` in [this line](https://github.com/dakshj48/8D-Audio-Converter/blob/330417840156047651f2db355055f3858681c410/audioCon.py#L28). Then try again restarting server and uploading file.